# XML Parser perl module is needed

Tags: perl, debian, libxml2

I'm trying to install intltool on Debian (Raspberry Pi). When running

```
  ./configure
```

The system always come back with the error:

```
checking for XML::Parser... configure: error: XML::Parser perl module is required for intltool
```

But I do have the latest version libxml and libxml-libxml-perl installed.

Can anyone help me interpret what is missing here?

Thank you!
Paul

Comment: What does `perl -MXML::Parser -e1` output? Also, `libxml-libxml-perl` installs/contains `XML::LibXML`, not `XML::Parser`.

Comment: Here is the output:Can't locate XML/Parser.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::Parser module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/armv7l-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.0/armv7l-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.0).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: The package you need is `libxml-parser-perl`.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libxml-parser-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxml-parser-perl is already the newest version (2.44-2+b1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lxkeymap python-cairo python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2
  python-xklavier
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.

Comment: Are you using the system Perl or a custom Perl? What does `which perl` output? For Debian, it must be `/usr/bin/perl`. You seem to have `/usr/local/bin/perl`. If that is not the system Perl, then installing packages using `apt-get` will not work.

Comment: yes, which perl turns up this: /usr/local/bin/perl

Comment: If this is the case, do I need to download a source package for perl and install manually? Are there additional packages needed as well? Thanks a lot1

Comment: No - you need to decide which Perl you want to install things in. If you want to use the system Perl, you can use `apt-get` to install Perl modules. If you want to use that other Perl, you will need to use `cpan` to install modules, like `cpan install XML::Parser`. You might still need to install some C libraries through `apt-get`, like `libexpat1-dev`.

Comment: Thank you, I used the     cpan install XML::Parser    it went through well. Interestingly, the which perl still turns out to be /usr/local/bin/perl, but this installation works fine with the intltool installation process. Wondering what's the reason for that...

Answer (score 3):

You need to install XML::Parser::Style::Tree module. Try with `cpanm`

```
cpanm XML::Parser::Style::Tree
```

Or using CPAN Shell

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install XML::Parser::Style::Tree
```

After that, the module will be installed and XML::Parser will work well.